# Meteor accounts-phone

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use okland: accounts-phone (after some updates of the code that I could use in meteor 1.8), the problem is that when I am trying to use it together with account-password, an error occurs when logging in:

message: ‘Match error: Match error: Unknown key in field phone in field user.phone’

Does anyone have a version of accounts-phone that works in 1.8?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've rewritten the package accounts-phone to fix the issues, if anyone wants to use the new package please go to https://atmospherejs.com/pablor21/accounts-password-phone